# Doctrine 2 get join field name

Tags: join, doctrine-orm

I want to find joined field name but I couldn't find how to get it. I have a scenerio like this. I have 2 table for instance User and roles. In user entity there is Roles field which is  a collection. I need a method which is getting a parameter releated object (Roles) and it must return role_id which is foreign key of user. I coulnd't find any method.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your entities are declared as below:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User
{  
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role")
     */
    private $roles;

    /**
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getRoles()
    {
        return $this->roles;
    }

    // Other fields and methods
    // ...
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Role
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    // Other fields and methods
    // ...
}
```

You can call [`Collection#map()`](https://github.com/doctrine/collections/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Collections/Collection.php#L223) to retrieve the IDs:

```
$user = $this->getUser();
$roleIDs = $user->getRoles()->map(function (Role $role) {
    return $role->getId();
});
```

Another option is to use the Doctrine connection to retrieve raw results.

Comment: I don't need the id, I need the column name of the foreign key. I'm in "role_id" I have to acquire. @Florent